# How do I capture a user's left-click in Windows Explorer?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

From what I've read, a shell extension is invoked when a user right-clicks on a file in Windows Explorer. Is there a way to capture an event or run a shell extension when a user left-clicks on a file?

I need to track the files a user selects as he selects them. Is that possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Subscribe to the SelectionChanged event on the shell folder view. This will also catch selection changes due to things other than mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the WinApi to check which window has focus. Is it an explorer window? Make sure it is the type of window you are looking for by checking its attributes. And if it is, check whenever the user presses the left mouse button using GetAsyncKeystate which notices **all** input.

When you get a left mouse click its time to check if the user clicked on a file representation. Loop trough the windows GUI items till you find the one having keyboard focus. Get the id of the container/frame for the file list by using the program Spy++. Now check if the focused/selected item is inside this frame and most importantly : **if it is a list item**. Get the name/caption attribute of the item and you are done!

I hope you realize that because of the length of this process i cant and wont give you the full code to do this... Tell me if there is anything you don't understand.